# PSQL: Find record where JSONB field with array of hashes contains some case insensitive value

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, jsonb

I need to find all the records in the PostgreSQL database (9.5) where  `connections` JSONB column with array of hashes containing some information. And this search query must be case-insensitive.

For example column would be `[{"type":"email", "value":"john@test.com", "comment": "Test"}, {"type":"skype", "value":"john.b", "comment": "Test2"}]`). And I need to find the record, where `connections` column contains entry with type: "skype" and value "JOHN.B".

```
# SELECT * FROM contacts;
  id | email |  connections                              
  ---+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | asd   | [{"type": "email", "value": "john@test.com"}, {"type": "skype", "value": "john.b"}]
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH t(id,email,connections) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'test','[
    {"type": "email", "value": "john@test.com"},
    {"type": "skype", "value": "john.b"}
  ]'::JSONB)
)
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE connections @> '[{"type": "skype"}]' 
AND connections @> '[{"value": "john.b"}]';
```

Result:

```
 id | email |                                     connections                                     
----+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | test  | [{"type": "email", "value": "john@test.com"}, {"type": "skype", "value": "john.b"}]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `>@`:

```
where connections @> '{"type":"skype"}' and
      connections @> '{"value":"john.b"}')
```